# Why doesn't python execute anything after 'unittest.main()' gets executed?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

So let's say I have the following:

```
import unittest

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

  def test001(self):
    print 'This is test001'

  def test002(self):
    print 'This is test002'

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
  print 'Done'
```

And the output is:

```
>> This is test001
>> This is test002
>> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>> Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

>> OK
```

And I was wondering why doesn't get to print 'Done' (or anything that comes after)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Pass `exit=False` to the `unittest.main()` call ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.main)):

```
unittest.main(exit=False)
```

Here's what I'm getting on the console:

```
$ python test.py
This is test001
.This is test002
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
Done
```

FYI, under the hood unittest's `TestProgram.runTests()` calls `sys.exit()` if the value of `exit` is `True` (which is by default):

```
def runTests(self):
    ...
    if self.exit:
        sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
```

Comment: The default value of `exit` is `True`, under the hood it's just calling `sys.exit()` after running tests.

Comment: Great, thank you, waiting for the 10 minutes to pass so I can accept your answer :)

Comment: Bear in mind that tests are not supposed to generate any output when they pass. If you replace the print statements with `pass` you will see a more normal output.

Comment: @holdenweb - It was only for demonstration purpose. I am normally not printing anything in my tests

Comment: @Herr Actress glad to hear it!